# How can I disable coloring of bash autocompletion of `cd` in bash?

Tags: bash, colors, nixos

In NixOS, both `ls` and bash autocompletion of `cd` color their results in a way that makes reading the names of writable directories very difficult (is it just me?).

I don't find a default ~/.bashrc that alias `ls`, so where does NixOS alias `ls`?

I used to use something like `dircolor ~/.mycolors` to change the color mapping to what is easier for reading. But that doesn't work in NixOS, and I was wondering why? That solution is still my preference if I can make it work.

I now disable the coloring of results of `ls`, by `unalias ls`.

How can I disable coloring of bash's autocompletion of  `cd` in bash? Or can I remap the color of bash's autocompletion results?
Running `set colored-stats off`in the same bash shell doesn't make any change.

Comment: Under which circumstances does `cd` output anything?`

Comment: ```cd <tab><tab>```?

Comment: @WhiteOwl That's the shell outputting something, not `cd`.

Comment: "Running `set colored-stats off`"... Did you run exactly that? That is supposed to be the author for a `bind` command: `bind 'set colored-stats off'`